# Server-Client chat program(Python sockets)

Tags: python, sockets, connection, client-server, chat

I want to create a server-client chat program using python sockets. I was trying to connect server(me) and client(my friend) through the internet, but still I can't understand the way to do it. Please help me.

**Server:**

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((my host, 12345))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr=s.accept()
while 1:
    msg=input(">>")    
    conn.send(msg.encode())
    print("Client:"+conn.recv(1024).decode())
```

**Client:**

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((my host, 12345))    
while 1:
    print("Server:"+s.recv(1024).decode())
    msg=input(">>")    
    s.send(msg.encode())
```

Comment: How can know my ip address for enter to the host in echo server?

Comment: it is more complex when you need to connect  through the internet. But server can use always `0.0.0.0`. Problem makes client because it has to use server external IP which server user can check only using web pages (because it is IP of Internet Provider router). Other problem is that some Internet Providers may change this IP every 24h. Other problem that Internet Provider may blocks some ports so you may have problem to use some non-standard ports.

Comment: Then how can I do i?.

Comment: on server you can try `0.0.0.0` and port `80` (standard port for HTTP) - `s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80)`. And then on server visit page ie. http://httpbin.org/ip to get external IP of your server (ie. at this moment I have external IP `83.23.34.81`), and client should use `s.connect("83.23.34.81", 80)` . But if your Internet Provider blocks port `80` then you may have to search other port - if only Internet Provider doesn't blocks all port because you can't change it. And your local router (which server uses to access internet) may blocks port but if you have login/password then you can change it.

Comment: How to know my server's closed ports?

Comment: all not used ports are close. There are tools to check which ports are used (open) - port scaners like [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html)

Comment: BTW: you run `nmap` on client computer to check server ports - see which ports are used and not blocked by routers. But it can't recognize which ports are open but blocked by routers. Or which port will blocked when you used them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com), it acts as a port forwarder without having to do it yourself. Download ngrok to your system32 folder and in your command prompt enter the following:
`ngrok tcp %PORT%`
This will create a TCP socket on localhost, ('0.0.0.0') so now you will have to do the following to your program:

**SERVER:**

`s.bind(('0.0.0.0', %PORT%))` # The port you used for ngrok`

**CLIENT:**

`s.connect(('NGROKHOSTIP', %NGROK FORWARDED PORT%))`

The NGROKHOSTIP can be found with a domain to IP program. You can do this yourself with Python.
Also, sorry I couldn't explain this better, I'm new to stackoverflow.